# Setting action from function parameter is null

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action

I have some actions in a view.

```
public class AView
{
    public Action Show { get; set; }
    public Action Hide { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to set those actions inside another class, by passing them as a parameter (I don't want to pass the whole class)

```
_reloader.SetupActions(Show, Hide);
```

`Reloader` is abstract, because there might be different ways of handling how Hide/Show must behave depending on the scenario we're in.

```
public abstract class Reloader : IReloader
{
    public void SetupActions(Action show, Action hide)
    {
        show = Show;
        hide = Hide;
    }

    protected virtual void Show() { ... } //what should be done when Show is invoked
    protected virtual void Hide() { ... } //same for Hiding
}
```

And for the current view, I might be using a `RapidReloader`, `SafeReloader`, etc. This bit is irrelevant, except that the injected reloader is specific to the current view.

Now my problem is simple and logic : when I'm in `SetupActions`, all parameters are null (because Actions haven't been set), and setting `Show` into `null` obviously does not work.

What can I do so that when Show.Invoke() happens my view, the ShowCode from the relevant reloader is called? I would like to avoid passing the whole view as a parameter.

Also, if you have a better design, I'm all ears. We might be in an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) situation

Comment: Yes, this might be a XY problem, but it won't be easy to help you unless you describe your business scenario. You are giving a description of your solution instead (kind of) :-)

Comment: Your `SetupActions` method makes no sense, because it assigns values to local variables only (method's arguments are local variables).

Comment: TargetClass is an abstract class that is overidden to handle how `Show` behaves depending on the scenario. It's actually our "reloader". Our views have a reloader injected and link their show/hide/etc to whatever reloader has been given by the injector. That way we can customize in a separate code how show/hide behaves for various types of views (alerts, refresh views, etc.)

Comment: I realize I have removed/oversimplified the question and its therefore lacking a bit of information. maybe my previous comment might help clarify

Comment: Why is `SourceClass.Show` an action? Why don't use a method that calls `TargetClassInstance.Show()`.

Comment: I have added more information and edited the code for more clarity, reflecting my actual problem. Hopefully it can now qualify as a good, valid question

Comment: So IReloader contains `void Show();` `void Hide();` and `SetupActions()`?

Comment: @dymanoid from my understanding that local variable is the reference I just passed from the view class. Basically I'm trying to set the view class' action from the outside without passing the whole class

Comment: @horotab yes it does

Comment: Whoops, but AView is not an IReloader, that was an edit mistake. only the reloader is an Ireloader. My view just uses an Irelaoder to know how to reload itself

Comment: Don't confuse _reference types_ with _references_. `Action` is a reference type, so your method gets a _reference to an object of type `Action`_. But that reference itself is passed by-value. You'd need a `ref` parameter here. But that won't work with a property though - you can't pass a property by `ref`.

Comment: Let me try to get you some solution, give me 2 minutes.

Comment: I understand the reference problem.  Are you suggesting my Actions should not be properties, and I should pass them using the ref keyword? Or that it would work like that but it's not a great choice?

Comment: I just mention that your `SetupAction` method currently does nothing. It assigns values to local variables and then returns. Those statements will be probably completely optimized away by the compiler/JITter (in release mode), so your method will be in fact just empty.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `System.ValueTuple` nuget package if you don't use .Net Framework 4.7 or newer.

```
public interface IReloader
{
    (Action Show, Action Hide) GetActions();
}


public abstract class Reloader : IReloader
{
    public (Action Show, Action Hide) GetActions()
    {
        return (Show, Hide);
    }

    protected virtual void Show() { }

    protected virtual void Hide() { }
}


public class FastReloader : Reloader { }


public class AView
{
    public Action Show{ get; set; }
    public Action Hide{ get; set; }


    public void IwantTheNewActions()
    {
        var reloader = new FastReloader();
        var actions = reloader.GetActions();
        Show = actions.Show;
        Hide = actions.Hide;
    }
}
```